# Required properties are missing from object error from JSON schema validator

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am receiving the error "Required properties are missing from object" when testing the JSON schema I have is valid but I can see the GroupName and GroupID fields exist in the object.

The JSON schema looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "http://localhost:8000/schema.json#",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Store Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "GroupName": {
            "description": "Group Name",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "GroupID": {
            "description": "Group ID",
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "[A-Z]{6,6}[A-Z2-9][A-NP-Z0-9]([A-Z0-9]{3,3}){0,1}"
        }
    },
    "required": ["GroupName","GroupID"],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe validator bug?

Comment: You might want to post the JSON document that is failing validation against this schema.